# Excel 12.0 Object Library guide

Tags: c#, excel

Does anyone know of an online guide? The best a developer reference on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb149067%28v=office.12%29.aspx) that reads more as a FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how the link you provided reads like a FAQ. Have a look at the [Excel Object Model Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb149081%28v=office.12%29.aspx) which is a sub topic of the link you provided.